# why does the div and the text go out in mobile?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, alignment

i'm doing some front-end stuffs and i got interrupt by an error
I want to get two cards in a section and i want them aligned horizontally. The problem is that in desktop version it works as well, but when i watch the mobile version it looks weird.

https://prnt.sc/XBbBVW2suZmE

the card goes off the section (the yellow space), the text goes outside the card and it isn't horizontally aligned.

```
<section class="blogdiv">
    <div class="cards">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Vespa</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                <a href="#" class="">leggi di più</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Vespa</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                <a href="#" class="">leggi di più</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

i'm using sass so, here's the scss of the blogdiv

```
&.blogdiv{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: $color2;
    color: $color1;
    .cards{
        .card{
            @include selection($color2, $color1);
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0.5rem;
            max-width: 60vw;
            max-height: 45vh;
            border: 1px solid $color1;
            color: $color1;
            .card-img-top{
                max-width: 60vw;
                max-height: 60vh;
            }
            .card-body{
                padding: 1rem;
                .card-title{
                    font-size: 3vh;
                    font-weight: 600;
                    margin: 0;
                }
                a{
                    @each $prefix in $prefixes {
                        #{$prefix}user-select: none;
                    }
                    cursor: default;
                    color: $navcolor2;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    &:hover{
                        color: black;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me correct form?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/8YF_SmEAFvia desktop version

Comment: what I would to get is like this https://prnt.sc/LCHWE5IUSFgs

Answer (score 0):

first you need to add a mobile reponsive section, using `@media screen`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px){
    .card{
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto; /*align horizontal auto*/
    }
}
```

and than, is just use the width --- heigth `px` to make proportional....

Comment: https://prnt.sc/5rBlHcISDXGo now the text is not right and the cards in desktop mode are not inline-block so they are in rows instaed of columns (prnt.sc/8YF_SmEAFvia BEFORE) (https://prnt.sc/lukYd30pqQf_ AFTER)

Comment: inside the `@media screen and (max-width: 960px)` you need to set up some things again, for example, you can give a margin btw your cards, `.card {margin-bottom: 30px;}`

Comment: checkout https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp for see how media queries work, but I remeber you, on mobile devices, you need to especify a `max-width`, that can be like `max-width: 480px` (wich normaly I use)